# Properties of a particular Kummer Surface

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry

Let $Y$ be the abelian variety $\mathbb{C}/\mathbb{Z}[i] \times \mathbb{C}/\mathbb{Z}[i] $ where $\mathbb{Z}[i]$ denote the set of Gaussian integers in $\mathbb{C}$. Let $X$ be the quotient of $Y$ by action of the group generated by the map $\eta(x,y)=(ix,iy)$. This group generated is of order 4, and is given by $\{e, -e, \eta, -\eta\}$ where $e$ is the identity map.

How can we show that $X$ is in fact a rational surface and has 10 singularities? I have perused several resources in regarding Kummer surfaces and could not find any literature using such a construction.

Comment: This is just basic surface theory, nothing particular to do with Kummer surfaces. Just list the fixed points of $\eta$ and $\eta^2$ and look at the action of the group on them.

Comment: The fact that it's rational needs a justification too (probably Castelnuovo's criterion).  One can do the same contruction in any dimension $n$ (take the quotient of $\mathbb C/\mathbb Z[i])^n$ by the diagonal action of $i$) and I believe it's unknown for what values of $n$ the quotient is a rational variety.

Comment: @Mark Are there any papers giving a detailed study of this particular construction? I can't seem to find any. I can only find papers detailing constructions where they   consider the quotient by an involution.

Comment: Check out Catanase-Oguiso-Truong, "Unirationality of Ueno-Campana’s threefold", where they prove the three-dimensional one is unirational.  You might also like Oguiso & Truong, "Explicit Examples of rational and Calabi-Yau threefolds with primitive automorphisms of positive entropy", which proves the three-dimensional one is rational if you use the curve with an order 6 auto instead.  For the 2-diml one I don't know a reference offhand, but I bet you can figure it out from these other papers.

Comment: @Mark Alright I will take a look at those papers. Thank you very much!